# How to force NSURLCache to cache response even if it still has a valid cache?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, caching, nsurlcache

I'm using NSURLCache (AFNetworking) to cache responses from my backend, setting `Cache-Control = max-age=3600, public`. This is working fine so far. When the user opens the app and the data is not older than one hour, it obtains it from the cache. When older, it loads it from the backend.

I also have a pull to refresh option that allows the user to get fresh data from the backend by overriding the cache even though it still has valid cached data, what also works fine.

The problem I have is, that the newly retrieved data (by overriding the cache) doesn't get cached. Scenario is like this:

1. User opens the app and data with timestamp x is being loaded from the backend with `Cache-Control = max-age=3600, public`
2. User studies the data for 10 minutes.
3. User now does a manual refresh of the data and new data with timestamp y is being pulled from the backend with `Cache-Control = max-age=3600, public`
4. User studies the new data for another 10 minutes and closes the app.
5. User opens the app again, but sees data with timestamp x instead of data with timestamp y

It seems to me that NSURLCache just doesn't cache data from the same resource as long as it has valid cached data, even though fresh data from the same resource came in in the meantime. Does anyone know how to tell NSURLCache to cache the most recent retrieved data even if it still has valid data? Or is it just working as designed? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You did not write what code did you use for the manual refresh. I guess you have used `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData` policy. I have not tested if stores the updated response in the cache. However if it does not store it, I would use 
`removeCachedResponseForRequest:` on shared `NSURLCache` and then load the data as usual.